# Create list of sequential numbers until next rounded number past x

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a list of sequential numbers in python from 1 to a specified number, but need to round the numbers off to one that's divisible by 10.

e.g. if my specificed number is `7` my list would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I've written the following code, which does work, but I'm unsure whether this is the best/most efficient way to write it, particularly if my numbers get large.

```
x = 33
i = 1
mylist = list()

while i <= x:
    mylist.append(i)
    i += 1

while mylist[len(mylist)-1] % 10 != 0:
    mylist.append(i)
    i += 1
```

which would output:

```
print mylist
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
```

Is there another better or more efficient (to run) way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def makeList(n):
    return range(1, n + 11 - (n % 10))
```

## EDIT

Noticed that when n is multiple of 10 no need to add 10.

```
def makeList(n):
    return range(1, n + 1 - (n % 10) + 10 * (n % 10 != 0))
```

Comment: thanks, much clearer than my attempt, and much much faster

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a simple range?

```
>>> def makeList(n):
    return list(range(1,1+n if n % 10 == 0 else 1+ 10*(1+n//10)))

>>> makeList(7)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> makeList(10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> makeList(11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Remark: in Python 2 you can drop the `list()` since `range()` is already a list (But in that case you have to make sure that you have imported Python 3's int division operator `//`).

Comment: I agree with the range part, but <insert boilerplate warning about float accuracy>.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not convinced that it was really an issue in this case, but better safe than sorry. I fixed it. As an added benefit, there is no longer any need to import math.